# Can you only parameterize the where clause?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

To prevent sql injection, I am trying to use parameterized queries. But it is not clear to me whether I should only paramterize the where clause or other parts of the query. For example, I am trying to improve the following query:

```
string strQ = @";WITH lstTable as (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + sort + @") AS RowNum, *
                FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM SystemMessage
                WHERE Deleted = 0  ";`
```

This query is being used in grid and based on user's selection, it will sort by the column name. Do I needed paramaterize 'sort' in this scenario?

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers but you can use a case expression in your order by clause that is based on a parameter value.

Comment: Either I lack an understanding of the question, or you lack an understanding of the problem. Parameterized queries will not (as far as I know) prevent you from having sql injection. Sanitizing the data prior to making the SQL request will help you more.

Comment: If your `sort` value is not entered by a user, but chosen from a list, then you don't have a SQL injection problem - otherwise, you do.

Comment: @fiprojects parameterized queries certainly will prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @fiprojects can you provide sample SQL query that demonstrate your statement (assuming no user input in SQL query and only parameters allowed)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: The SQL query is a string so when you pass a non string item to the query the low level drive has to guess the type.  If pass a number 1 to the query and the database has the type a float you could loose accuracy of the results.  If the database has a field defined at a string and you pass 1.23 the driver may convert the object to a number and then you would get a mis-match in types.  So it is "best" to always use parameters for every variable.

Comment: I think its safe to say that I lacked an understanding of the question - and I also learned that "*parameterized queries certainly will prevent SQL injection*" Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that you can't use parameters directly for this use case. However the fact if you need to use parameters or not depends on how `sort` gets populated.

If it is a list of column names that are hard coded and the user just picks which indexes in the list are going to be chosen you don't need to worry about parameterizing, the user does not have direct input in the query so they can't inject code in to it.

If the user is providing the column names directly you must clean up the user input before passing it in, a way to do that is use the sql function [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to clean up the input.

```
string strQ = @"
declare @query nvarchar(max)
set @query = ';WITH lstTable as (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY' + QUOTENAME(@sortColumn) + ') AS RowNum, *
                FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM SystemMessage
                WHERE Deleted = 0 '
exec sp_executesql @query";
```

What that will do is whatever string you pass in to `@sortColumn` it will properly wrap `[ ]` around that string value. It then uses that excaped value in the dynamicly generated string and runs that with `sp_executesql`.

One important note, this example only works with a single column name currently, you would need a `QUOTENAME` and a new parameter per column you wanted to add in to the query. If you did try passing in `FirstName, LastName` it would become

```
;WITH lstTable as (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FirstName, LastName]) AS RowNum, *
       FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM SystemMessage
       WHERE Deleted = 0
```

when executed so it would attempt to find a column named "`[FirstName, LastName]`" and would fail.

Comment: What if the string passed is `select 1];drop table tablename --`? How would qouatname protect from that?

Comment: @ZoharPeled It would become `[select 1]];drop table tablename --]` Sql treats a `]]` inside a `[ ]` set as `]` interpeted as text. similar to how if you do `"\\"` in C# to get just a `\ `. In the MSDN documentation they show an example of it.

Comment: Good to know! I wasn't aware of the fact that `QUOTENAME` actually escapes characters inside the string.